# How can I fix "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:" when trying to install django-visits

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install django-visits, but anytime I run the **"pip install django-visits"** command, I get the following error:

````
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\samuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Samuel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-insta
ll-8t2j3cs9\\distribute\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Samuel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8t2j3cs9\\distribute\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__fi
le__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8t2j3c
s9\distribute\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8t2j3cs9\distribute\
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8t2j3cs9\distribute\setuptools\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
      File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8t2j3cs9\distribute\setuptools\extension.py", line 5, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
      File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8t2j3cs9\distribute\setuptools\dist.py", line 7, in <module>
        from setuptools.command.install import install
      File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8t2j3cs9\distribute\setuptools\command\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from setuptools.command import install_scripts
      File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8t2j3cs9\distribute\setuptools\command\install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
      File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8t2j3cs9\distribute\pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
        register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
    AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.```


How can I fix it?
````

Answer (score 1):

Simply try `pip3 install django-visits` and see if it works. If not, follow the solution below.

I think this is because `python3.7` and `pip` were installed from different sources.
I suggest using python's inbuilt facility to install pip i.e

```
python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

This should install `pip3` and `pip3.x` where x in `python3.x`.

Comment: For which cmd is that?

Comment: Thanks. I've been able to solve with "easy_install django-visits"

Comment: If this answer helped in your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information